# Good service to host CPU intensive web application

Tags: google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Currently, I am a happy user of google app engine.

However, I am planning to host a CPU intensive web app (which is going to apply all sorts of signal processing algorithm), is there any other good service which is available?

As I realize google app engine has placed restriction on per minute CPU time.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Per-minute_Quotas

Comment: with free option like GAE ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been very happy with mediatemple for two or three sites which are very cpu intensive, they can switch you between plans temporarily if you need burst capacity plus their phone support is excellent and they will talk to you on skype.

Answer (score 0):

Would Amazon EC2 "[High CPU Instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)" be a possibility? From their page:

> High-CPU Extra Large Instance
>
> - 7 GB of memory
> - 20 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each)
> - 1690 GB of instance storage
> - 64-bit platform
> - I/O Performance: High